# Python stripe can't delete connect account | 'str' object has no attribute 'refresh_from'

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I am using stripe connect and a custom interface to create/manage stripe users.

I want now to delete a stripe connect account, the balance is 0 ofc., eventhough it should not matter with test keys. According to the [docu](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/delete) for stripe connect it is super simple to delete an account:

> With Connect, you may delete Custom accounts you manage.
>   Custom accounts created using test-mode keys can be deleted at any time. Custom accounts created using live-mode keys may only be deleted once all balances are zero.

That is my code:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(id=data_received["user_id"]).first()

stripe_acc_id = user.stripe_connect_acc_id

db_session.delete(user)

if stripe_acc_id != None:
    print ("User has stripe connect account", stripe_acc_id)
    try:
        stripe.Account.delete(stripe_acc_id)
    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'status': 'failed', 'reason': str(e)})

db_session.commit()
```

But it does not work, I am getting this error:

```
{"status": "failed", "reason": "'str' object has no attribute 'refresh_from'"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for static methods like `stripe.Account.delete` as documented was actually only added to the library [very recently](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2240---2019-04-03).

Unless you're using the latest version of the library, you need to instead slightly counter-intuitively fetch the account first, and then delete it:

```
account = stripe.Account.retrieve('acct_1DyHD2HPqAmBZVG2') 
account.delete()
```

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I was running an older version of Stripe and I simply needed to run this to update it:
pip install --upgrade stripe

Answer (score -1):

This error is caused because your python-stripe version does not support this delete method with the id argument. I faced the same issue while deleting the coupon with the old stripe version 2.6.0.

Comment: That answer was already proposed and accepted 3 years ago, with much more detail.